# Definition of two point correlators in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, greens-functions, correlation-functions

In QFT, The two-point correlator (Green function) for operators $O_A, O_B$ is given by $\langle O_AO_B \rangle $. Why is not defined by $ \langle O_A O_B\rangle -\langle O_A\rangle \langle O_B\rangle $, which is also the covariance in statistics? Isn't this definition captures the notion of correlation better than just the $\langle O_A O_B\rangle $? Is it because one point function like $\langle O_A\rangle$ is trivial?

Answer (score 3):

$\langle O_1O_2\rangle$ is called the *full* correlation function. $\langle O_1O_2\rangle-\langle O_1\rangle\langle O_2\rangle$ is called the *connected* correlation function. They are both important concepts, and they are both used in practice. It is true that the second one is, in general, more useful, because (as is noted in the OP), it satisfies the clustering property, which reflects the locality of the corresponding object.

It should be noted, though, that it is typically the case that $\langle O_i\rangle=0$, in which case these functions are identical, and there is no need to specify which one we are using.

Comment: according to wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_correlation , it seems the later is referred as correlation function in statistics? Why is it called connected? and under what are the different meanings they behind the two definitions?

Comment: It is called *connected* because only connected Feynman diagrams contribute to it, if you calculate this function perturbatively. I don't understand your other questions.